# Writing multiple TIFF files to PDF file

Tags: python, image, pdf, imagemagick, tiff

I wanted to write a python script where I take a bunch of tiff files and display them all to one giant pdf file for viewing purposes. I tried using the python command `im.save(outfile, "PDF)`  but that saves one tiff file to one pdf file separately. What should I do to write the tiff file in the same pdf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use Python, just use imagemagick's `convert` on the command line:

```
$ convert *.tif pictures.pdf
```

Comment: Is there a way to put multiple .tiff files on one page of the output pdf file?